# How to select value from multiple select HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select

I have this form with a select:

```html
<form name="form" method="post" action="registr.php">
  <select name="type">
    <option value="std">Standard</option>
    <option value="stud">Student</option>
    <option selected hidden value=""></option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Invia" onclick="return validation();">
</form>
```

I have to check the data I send with a javaScript function.
if I have not selected either student or standard, the form must return false.
this is the function, but it doesn't works:

```
function validation() {
  var type = document.form.type.value;
  if (type == "") {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Script does work, and only return true when one of those is selected (tested in Chrome).

Comment: For a more cross browser (and safe/modern) way to access the element, don't use `type` as a variable name, and combined it with `querySelector`, e.g. `var val = document.querySelector('select').value`

Answer (score 0):

You should add the call to the validation function to the submit event of the form itself - not directly to the button.
The below example will open an alert dialog if neither student nor standard is selected.

```js
function validation() {
  var type = document.form.type.value;
  if (type == "") {
    alert("Please select something");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form name="form" method="post" action="registr.php" onsubmit="return validation();">
  <select name="type">
    <option value="std">Standard</option>
    <option value="stud">Student</option>
    <option selected hidden value=""></option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Invia">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call validation method in form tag onsubmit, because if form get false then it not going to submit otherwise it will submit.

```
<form name="form" method="post" onsubmit="return validation();" action="registr.php">
<select name="type">
<option value="std">Standard</option>
<option value="stud">Student</option>
<option selected hidden value=""></option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Invia">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script does work, you can also try to add an `id` to your select option:

```js
function validation() {
  var id = document.getElementById("selecttype");
  var type = id.options[id.options.selectedIndex].value;
  if (type == "") {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
  

<form name="form" method="post" action="registr.php">
  <select name="type" id="selecttype">
    <option value="std">Standard</option>
    <option value="stud">Student</option>
    <option selected hidden value=""></option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Invia" onclick="return validation();">
  </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are accessing the select field wrongly.
Try this

```js
var type = document.forms[0].elements.type.value;
```